# How to increase Terminal font size on OSX?

Tags: macos, fonts

I thought that doing this would be extremely easy. I have done so many searches in Google to find out how to do this, but nothing ever comes up. I searched "increase terminal size osx" but none of the websites match. How do I increase the font size of the terminal?
Thanks!

Comment: is [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/change-font-size-in-terminal-window-121975/) applicable?

Comment: Note that in later years, the font-size selector became a list instead of a type-in field. But you can add entries to the list by clicking on a little menuBar dropDown in the upper-left that looks like an ellipses inside a circle. The pick "Edit Sizes..."

Answer (score 43):

It is in fact quite easy.  Select **Preferences** from the application menu, then the **Settings** tab.  In the settings notebook, select the terminal profile you want to change (usually **Basic**), then select the **Text** page (should be selected already); **Font** is the first item on the page.[image: Example of settings window]

Comment: Note: the large custom view Terminal adds to the font panel forces the panel into it's "compact" mode which allows 14pt and 18pt but no sizes in between. To fix this, simply resize the font panel to be taller, taking it out of the compact mode.

Comment: Changing the font size like this seemed to have no effect for me, at first. Pressing `Command`+`0` fixed it. (commenting here in case others run into this problem)

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using Oh My Zsh it seems. Any ideas how to get it working with that tool?

Comment: Required Step: After updating preferences, you need to start a new window and then close the old window. This will save the new preferences.

Comment: `Command` + `0` is cool and refreshed my terminal with updated values instantly, what does it do @LaurenceGonsalves?

Answer (score 31):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>  (to increase)
<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>  (to decrease)

Comment: Is the `Shift` added in Lion? In Snow Leopard it's just `Command`+`+/-`

Comment: @nine9ths Shift is not needed!

Comment: What is the shortcut for default font size ?

Comment: This still works in El Capitan.

Comment: Also working on current Big Sur.

Comment: It's not permanent.

Comment: `command`+`shift`+`+/-` works for Big Sur

Answer (score 3):

For me the other answers did not change font size permanently on Monterey 12, Terminal Version 2.12.5. Instead what worked was increasing font size using Command + '+', and then in the menu select "Shell > Use Settings as default"

Answer (score 2):

[step 1: open terminal > preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDtAb.jpg)

[step 2: click on profiles > Text(tab) > click on change button in front of font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptsc6.png)