# What is the shortcut for "increase font size" in Terminal using non-english keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, keyboard-layout

I have a Turkish keyboard and in my keyboard there isn't a standalone '+' character. So following doesn't work for me

[How to increase Terminal font size on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/298702/how-to-increase-terminal-font-size-on-osx)

Following is my keyboard layout. What is the shortcut for "increase font size" in Terminal?

[image: Turkish keyboard layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered by chance that following key combination increases font size (Zoon In).

<kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> (+ is located on <kbd>4</kbd> key)

You can use default shortcut keys for Zoom out and Reset:

- Zoom out: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>
- Reset zoom: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is get a “+” sign, so normally you'd do <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, but since you need a command modifier to increase the text size, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: It won't work. In my case for + character i use shift+4, when i press shift+cmd+4 it does not increase font. cntrl+cmd+(-) works though even in sublime 'Larger text' is mapped to cmd+(+)