# How to find current point size on MacOS Catalina Terminal utility? Not how to increase or decrease point size

Tags: terminal.app, macos-catalina

Is there a way to find out what point size my terminal is using? I open up a terminal and hit CMD + until it looks good, but would like to find that setting and stick that number in the profile instead. I tried stty -a, tty, and this article: https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/terminal/trmlstrtup/mac and this here: [How to increase Terminal font size on OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/298702/how-to-increase-terminal-font-size-on-osx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a couple of pretty clunky ways to do it, one 'you count' & the other 'check in the prefs, live'.

1. 'You count.'
   The default is 10pt. Every  <kbd>+</kbd>  after that increases the size by 1pt.
   Default size is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd>  so hit that, then count up for each  <kbd>+</kbd>  you press.
2. Visually, from prefs.
   Open terminal Prefs. The first tab is Text. In there is Font showing the current defaut. Next to that, click Change…
   With the Font picker open, click back onto the Terminal window you were working in, then use  <kbd>+</kbd>  or  <kbd>-</kbd>  to change the font size until you're happy.
   The picker will reflect the current size, even if it's not a regular size in the list below, e.g. 15.
   Close the picker to save your new default.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I tried 2 from prefs. If I don't click on the Size field, it does not go into edit-from-keyboard mode, nor have the focus. So + just gives the error sound. If I click on the size number, the field is editable, so when I type +, it erases the number a replaces it with +. However their is a slider with a knob, and if I slide that it dynamically changes the point size in the open terminal window and I found the size.

Comment: You don't need to click the font picker at all. You click back onto the Terminal window you were working in.